# single node cluster work on multinide cluster?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed, hdfs

I had written mapreduce java code for single machine cluster without using Tool ,will it work on multi node cluster or i have to make changes?
Following code tokenize the string and count term frequency per text file

```
public class tr 
    {
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text,Text,IntWritable>
    {
       Text word=new Text();
       IntWritable one=new IntWritable(1);
               String imptoken;
       public static  List<String> stopwords=new ArrayList<String>();
       public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output,Reporter reporter) throws IOException
       {
                       addwords();
              String line=value.toString();
                      line=line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]"," ").toLowerCase();
                      StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line);
          while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
                 imptoken=st.nextToken();
                             if(stopwords.contains(imptoken))
               {

               }               
               else
               {
                   word.set(imptoken);
                   output.collect(word, one); 
               }                              
                   }
    }
          public void addwords() throws IOException
      {
     FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
     Path stop=new Path("/user/hduser/stopword.txt");
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(stop)));
     String stopword=br.readLine();
     while(stopword!=null)
     {
         stopwords.add(stopword);
         stopword=br.readLine();
     }

      }

}
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text,IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public void reduce(Text key,Iterator<IntWritable> value,OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output,Reporter reporter) throws IOException
    {
        int sum=0;
        while(value.hasNext())
        {
            sum=sum+value.next().get();
        }   
                   /* Path paths=new Path("/user/hduser/input1/");
        FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(paths);
                    Path[] list = FileUtil.stat2Paths(status);
                    String keystr=key.toString();
                    for(Path file : list)
                    { 
                       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(file)));
               String word=br.readLine();
               while(word!=null)
               {
                 if(word.equals(keystr))
                 {
                     sum=0;
                 }
                 word=br.readLine();
                }

                     }*/

                     output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
            }       
    }

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{             
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    Path[] paths = new Path[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) 
    {
        paths[i] = new Path(args[i]);
    }

    FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(paths);
            Path[] listedPaths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(status);

    FSDataInputStream in = null;
    for (Path p : listedPaths) 
    {
         JobConf conf = new JobConf(tr.class);
             conf.setJobName("tr");

             conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
             conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

             conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
             conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
             conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

             conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
                     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

             String name=p.getName();
             String absolutepath=p.getParent().toString()+"/"+name;

             FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(absolutepath));
                     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

                     JobClient.runJob(conf); 

                     Path local=new Path("/home/hduser/meproj/projectfiles/");
                     Path source=new Path(args[1]+"/"+"part-00000");

                     fs.copyToLocalFile(source, local);

                     File  file=new File("/home/hduser/meproj/projectfiles/part-00000");
                     file.renameTo(new File("/home/hduser/meproj/projectfiles/"+name));
                     fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: It should do unless you have explicitly coded it in such a way that it wouldn't. Is there any particular reason why you're using the old hadoop API?

Comment: I am new to hadoop ,i have not understood MapReduce programming properly i don,t know how to run MapReduce program per file in corpus so can u tell me alternative method to implement MapReduce program per file on single and multi node cluster

Answer (score 1):

When you write a program for Hadoop using it will work for all cluster setups, unless you are specifically doing something to break that, like working on local files on one machine.

You are doing the work in the Mapper and Reducer in a setup independent fashion(which you are supposed to do), so it should work everywhere.

This is unrelated to your question, but you should not be looping over the files and running independent Jobs on each path.  Really you should run one Job on all of those. You can either put all of those separate paths in the same folder and specify that folder as the input. Or you can run hadoop on multiple paths (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593243/hadoop-job-taking-input-files-from-multiple-directories))