# Hadoop job taking input files from multiple directories and detecting each one in map phase

Tags: file, hadoop, input, mapreduce

In a job there are two input files that they are at the two different directories, In [Hadoop job taking input files from multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593243/hadoop-job-taking-input-files-from-multiple-directories) , we can read files from multiple directories. The files have the same name but they are in different name folders.

`C1/part-0000
C2/part-0000`

 Is it possible that detecting files in map phase?
Some thing like:

       `public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            if (First file) {
             ...
                    context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
                }
            } else {
             //Second file
                ...
                    context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
                }
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Check it in setup phase

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileSplit split = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
    Path path = split.getPath();
    String name = path.getName();
    ...
```

Don't check it in map method for every row, because each mapper is created for 1 input split.